# How to add a csv export file name to a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, csv, export, filenames

I export a lot of mysql query results to csv, and would like to incorporate the export file name to the query.

The default name is query_result.csv, so this is what I would like to change.

Example:
select *
from users
SOME MAGIC TO SET CSV FILE NAME

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can set a variable name to hold the csv file name and use it in the statement.

```
SET @file_name = file_name;

SELECT * FROM USERS @file_name;
```

Note that also, the variables only last per session.
Here is a link to the full documentation on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html